# rCharts: plot is working fine in RStudio but empty in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

Using the code below

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)    
hair_eye_male <- subset(as.data.frame(HairEyeColor), Sex == "Male")
n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, 
            group = "Eye", 
            data = hair_eye_male, 
            type = 'multiBarChart')
n1
```

I got this plot in RStudio

[image]

I want to create a shiny app for this plot. I created the app using the code below

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(uiOutput("tb")))
server <- function(input,output){

  output$hair_eye_male <- renderChart({

    hair_eye_male <- subset(as.data.frame(HairEyeColor), Sex == "Male")
    n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = "Eye", data = hair_eye_male, 
                type = 'multiBarChart')
    return(n1) 
  })
  output$tb <- renderUI({
    tabsetPanel(tabPanel("First plot", 
                         showOutput("hair_eye_male")))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, shiny app didn't render the plot. It appeared empty. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using rCharts package with r shiny you need to specify which javascript library you are using.

By adding line `n1$addParams(dom = 'hair_eye_male')` to `renderChart()` and specifying which library you are using in `showOutput()`, code will work.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(rCharts)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(uiOutput("tb")))
server <- function(input,output){

  output$hair_eye_male <- renderChart({

    hair_eye_male <- subset(as.data.frame(HairEyeColor), Sex == "Male")
    n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = "Eye", data = hair_eye_male, 
                type = 'multiBarChart')
    n1$addParams(dom = 'hair_eye_male') 
    return(n1) 
  })
  output$tb <- renderUI({
    tabsetPanel(tabPanel("First plot", 
                         showOutput("hair_eye_male", lib ="nvd3")))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I got this error using your code
Error: unused argument (lib = "nvd3").

Comment: @aelwan: I installed rCharts by using command: `require(devtools)
install_github('ramnathv/rCharts')`